# Return an enum class

Tags: java, templates, enums

I have a class in which I have a number of private Enums. 
In the initiator, I pass a number of arguments as Strings and for each I call a funtion to convert it to the approriate value. For instance, if the member is a Double I will call a function I wrote that calls Double.value(String str) and returns it, or null.

```
public Boolean stringToBool(String value)
{
    return ( value.toUpperCase() == "TRUE" ) ? true : false;
}

public Double stringToDouble(String value)
{
    return ( value == null ) ? null : Double.valueOf(value);
}
```

My question concerns the enums. Again I call a function I wrote passing the value in string and the class if the enum the member is associated with. How do I return a certain enum? Can I do that? Or shall I just cast it in the constructor?

```
public class MyClass
{
    private enum ENUM1 {
        HIGH,
        MED,
        LOW
    }

    private enum ENUM2 {
        DIFFICULT,
        MODERATE,
        EASILY
    }

    private Integer id;
    private String designSpec;
    private Double maxThickness;
    private ENUM1 enum1;
    private Boolean springs;
    private ENUM2 enum2;

    public Alloy()
    {
    }



    public Alloy(String designSpec,
                 String maxThickness,
                 String enum1, String enum2, String springs)
    {
        this.designSpec = designSpec;
        this.maxThickness = stringToDouble(maxThickness);
        this.enum1 = stringToEnum(ENUM1.class, enum1);
        this.enum2= stringToEnum(ENUM2.class, enum2);
        this.springs =  stringToBool(springs);
    }

    public Boolean stringToBool(String value)
    {
        return ( value.toUpperCase() == "TRUE" ) ? true : false;
    }

    public Double stringToDouble(String value)
    {
        return ( value == null ) ? null : Double.valueOf(value);
    }

    public Enum stringToEnum(Class enumType, String value)
    {
        return ( value == null ) ? null : Enum.valueOf(enumType, value);
    }
```

My class is something like this. I want to know if the stringToEnum can be made to return ENUM1 or ENUM2 using just that function. Does it have to do anything with templates?

Comment: Can't you use the enum directly? (same for other types, there's no need to stringify everything).

Comment: Initially I did, but the value could be null (I am communicating with a database) so I want to handle the null case in the function

Comment: What's the question? Just return. What issues are you facing?

Comment: @Pshemo, yeah I actually changed that, I think I copied an earlier version of the function. Why is htere a problem with value.toUpperCase() == "TRUE"

Comment: @Boris, Well, the function returns Enum but the way I understand it, I can't assign an Enum object to my ENUM1 member, can I? I think I can cast it since it's an Enum but I was wondering if I can write a function that return somethink like Enum<T> and the return will be the enum class I specified when I call the function

Comment: @AndreasAndreou Test this code `"foo".toUpperCase()=="foo".toUpperCase()`. For objects `==` checks if references point to same instances (same objects) not if objects have same state, but each time you invoke `toUpperCase()` you are creating new (separate) instance of String, so even if they hold same informations, they are stored in different locations in memory. In other words `==` tests *identity*, not *state*.

Comment: Yeah, good point. Actually forgot about it. What happens when you take a year off programming... :( Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

ENUM1 and ENUM2 are different classes; they both extend java.lang.Enum.  You could write a method that would take an Enum as a parameter, and pass either of them to that method.  To do what you're talking about, you would then have to use instanceof to determine which class was passed in, in order to do anything specific with it.

I haven't tried this, but you might be able to use general enum methods to convert between strings and enums, as long as the strings matched or were declared equivalent for those enums.  See the enum methods toString() and valueOf() to see if they suit you.

You could also have 2 methods, one that took ENUM1 and one that took ENUM2; they aren't going to be able to share code much anyway.